# Searching for my most recently created bookmarks

Tags: discussion, support

I have a couple hundred bookmarks I've collected over 9 years or so on SO. There are seven pages of them on the Bookmark tab in my profile. Today I wanted to find a bookmark I recently created, but could not do so easily. The Bookmarks tab has sort buttons for "Newest" and "Added", but surely I could not tell you want these mean. Neither appeared to do what I needed. Does Newest mean newest question, newest bookmark anyone has added, or something else? What does Added mean?

Comment: "Newest" is almost certainly question creation date. "Added" *seems* to be when you bookmarked it, assuming I'm remembering my bookmarking history correctly. Is it possible the question you bookmarked was deleted or something?

Comment: If you did bookmark it before last sunday, it should be part of this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1238013) assuming the question is not deleted. And my sort seems to match what @JohnMontgomery noticed for the "added" tab.

Comment: I made a keyboard macro ([own Arduino Leonardo-based macro keyboard](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/keyboard-print-skips-keys/75525#75525)) to transfer all bookmark URLs to a text file, removing them in the process (at 400 bookmarks it becomes unwieldy with the paging and no search facility).